# ax^2+bx+c type inequality solve by completing the square using prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

When solving `f(x)=-3x^2+5x-4` inequality qusetion using completing the square method using prolog how can substract two fractions(eg: `4/3 - 25/36`) as it is without taking the floating point values. The answer wants to be as a fraction.

Answer (score 3):

In SWI-Prolog, using rational numbers:

```
?- X is (4 rdiv 3) - (25 rdiv 36).
X = 23 rdiv 36.
```

Answer (score 3):

SWI-Prolog implements [rational numbers](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=rational).
I get

```
?- X is 4 rdiv 3 - 25 rdiv 36.
X = 23 rdiv 36.
```